# Responsive image and List items

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a header part of a responsive design. Can anyone tell me how to **keep same height** in both list items total height and responsive image height, responsive image height will be change according to the resolution, what i need to do is according to that height add more list items or change list items bottom margin and height (both should be increase or decrease and add/remove items to keep a clean look.)

Can anyone help me in this matter to solve? (I'm using HTML5, CSS3, Jquery and PHP if needed)

[image: Design]

http://jsfiddle.net/ST7xy (This is a demo)

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" width="100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend floating it all inside a div, with an adjustable height depending on resolution then using percentages on your heights, so making the main image 100% and the list's (4 in your example) 25% each.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNkuH/)

## css:

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
}

.navigation{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

.list{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.list li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    height: 23.5%;
}

.list li:last-child{
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 23.5%;
}

.list li a{
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    line-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but have little issue with that in my case. I need to increase or decrease margin between each item to keep that nice look, else `li` height will be so big when we display this in a big resolution.

Comment: Why not use percentages on those too?

Comment: Just need to fix up the image so it is adjusting and also your container div, 2 secs

Comment: Cool. Any idea how to add more items when the resolution is very high?

Comment: Okay something like this, you just need to adjust the percentages to match: http://jsfiddle.net/Jk2TU/

Comment: If you want to be more advanced I would recommend using JQuery, you could collect all your `<li>` element's work out how many their are, divide them by 100 then get your percentage and set it to the css height.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this to work with css alone. You need to use `jquery`.

Use

```
var navHeight = $(".navigation").height();
```

to get the height of the navigation div. And on any change you need to assign that height to div `image` like :

```
$(".image").height(navHeight);
```

So basically  :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var navHeight = $(".navigation").height(); 
   $(".image").height(navHeight);
});

$(window).resize(); //on page load
```

Jus giving an insight and you can build on from here..:)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want and what you need

[Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/75m9S/)

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var leftHeight = $('.image').height() - 5;
    $('.navigation').css({
        'height': leftHeight
    });
    var rightHeight = $('.navigation').height();
});
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color:#000;
    height:inherit;
}
.list li {
    padding:0;
    
    height:25%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.list li a {
    display: block;
    background: gray;
    height:90%;
}
.image {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

As you can see the query is simple ad straight forward. I assign the height of the image div to the navigation div.

In the CSS i have used percentages to match the parent `ul`. So incase you using 4/6/8 list item's you will have to change this percentage accordingly.

Enjoy!